# Does the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ have a solution in natural numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does the equation
$$x^2+y^2=1$$
have a solution $(x,y)$ in the natural numbers? If we assume natural numbers do not include $0$, can this equality hold? I assumed it is false, since only $1$, $-1$ and $0$ give that solution but $0$ and $-1$ cannot be used. So there is no way it can be true. Is this correct?

Comment: Try to look for solutions such that $x\ge 19$.

Comment: Clearly false. Putting minimum value of this expression is 2.

Comment: what do you mean look for solutions above 19

Answer (score 1):

No. Simply put, 
$$x^2=1-y^2$$
Therefore, $x=\pm \sqrt{(1-y^2)}$. Talking about natural numbers lets keep
$x=+\sqrt{(1-y^2)}$ from the first quadrant and therefore add another condition $x\geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$.

Since root implies that for real solutions
\begin{align} 
& 1-y^2 \geq 0 \\
\implies & -1 \leq y \leq 1
\end{align}

The intersection of this condition with $y\geq 0$ gives $y \leq 0 \leq 1$.

Similarly, $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Therefore if $x$ and $y$ has to take natural values then $x$ and $y$ have to be 1 but then they wouldn't lie on our circle.

Hence why the statement is false.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for the advice and warm welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some geometric interpretation to the answer of Vidhu.

The equation $x^2+y^2=1$ describes the set of point in the unit circle in the plane. By drawing the circle you can easily find all natural (or even integer) solutions.